the application crashes on this line private val operationtexView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.operation)
When I launch an application on my phone, it does not open. The problem is in this line private val operationtexView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.operation)
package com.daniff.calculator

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlin.text.StringBuilder

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var numOne = ""
    private var numTwo = ""
    private var operation = ""

    private val operationtexView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.operation)

    private val buttn0: TextView = findViewById(R.id.buttn0)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        initListener()
    }

    private fun initListener(){
        buttn0.setOnClickListener { AddNumberInput( 0.toString() ) }
    }  

   private fun AddNumberInput(number: String){
        if(operation == ""){
            numOne += number

        } else{
            numTwo += number
        }
        operationtexView.text = StringBuilder().append(operationtexView.text.toString()).append(number)               


}

I've been commenting on the whole code and it fails on this line private val operationtexView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.operation)

Please always provide the error message of errors you encounter. Usually with the full strack trace, but in this case just the message will probably suffice.

You might be encountering a java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference.
This happens because the method findViewById(R.id.operation) is called at the time the MainActivity instance is instantiated within the Java runtime, but before the onCreate() method of the Android activity lifecycle has been invoked, where you're calling the setContentView(), which is necessary for findViewById() to function correctly.
However, you can postpone the findViewById invocation by using the Kotlin lazy delegate, which delays this action until the property is first accessed, as follows:
private val operationtexView: TextView by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
    findViewById(R.id.operation)
}

I've used LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE because we don't need synchronization here since views can only be accessed from the main thread.
Also, you may want to consider using the View binding approach that is recommended by Google for traditional Android views.
